# Try to learn more about linear operator,subspace and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that for every subspace $F$ and every linear transformation $L$ of linear space $V$ and $\dim V=n$ is $\dim L(F)+\dim\ker L=\dim(F+\ker L)$

I know that $F$ and $\ker L$ are subspaces of the same vector space, so we have $\dim(F+\ker L)=\dim F +\dim\ker L -\dim(F\cap\ker L)$. And if we have some basis for subspace $F, B=\{f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_k\}\ k\le n,$ and they are linearly independent, then $L(f_1), L(f_2),\ldots,L(f_n)$ are linearly independent if $N(L)=0$, because this is  an isomorphic linear transformation (iff they have same dimension, but here we have) then $\dim L(F)=\dim F$,then we have $\dim(F\cap\ker L)=0$, but I do not know is this good how I explain?

Comment: I would attempt to prove this in a manner similar to proofs I have seen for the rank-nullity theorem. How do these go again? Start with a basis for the $\ker L$. If $L(F) = 0$ then you are done. Otherwise, you can extend the basis to account for $L(F)$. Extending by one basis element at a time, you will have that the sum on the left is a direct sum, and eventually end up with a basis for $\ker L$ and $\im F$. I haven't worked through this proof, but this seems like a natural direction to take it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of the isomorphism theorems for modules (in particular, vector spaces). 
We have $$ L(F) \simeq \frac{F}{F\cap kerL} \simeq \frac{F+kerL}{kerL}.$$
Computing the dimensions we have $$dimL(F) = dim(F+kerL) - dimKerL.  $$

Comment: I presume you are using the third (diamond) isomorphism theorem to establish the second isomorphism. Your first isomorphism comes from the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Yes.

Alternatively, $L(F) \subset L(V)$ is a subspace and needs to correspond to a subspace of $V/kerL$ via the isomorphism $L(V) \simeq  V/ kerL$. Every subspace of  $V/kerL$ has the form $M/kerL$ for some $kerL\subset M \subset V$, since the isomorphism $L(V) \simeq  V/ kerL$ is explicit, one can verify $M = F+kerL$.